# имя таблицы как параметр sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Может кто подскажет ответ на такую задачу:

Есть таблицы в базе данных, которые имеют названия `table15`, `table14`...`table00`. Необходимо написать хранимую процедуру, которая в качестве одного из параметра должна получать год, по которому и должна определяться таблица для выполнения запросов.

Динамический SQL использовать при этом не получается, так как код процедуры большой! Есть какое то решения для данной задачи?

Comment: Как год связан с таблицами?

Comment: в коде происходит обращение к таблицам, например `Select * from table14 FULL JOIN table15 ON  table14.col1 = table15.col1 ......`

Comment: Я что-то не понимаю? Что Вы подразумеваете под годом?

Comment: скрипт хранимой процедуры!!!

Comment: Если уж никак не хочется сделать правильно (вместо N таблиц сделать ровно одну), можете создать соответствующий VIEW, что-то типа `CREATE VIEW allYears AS SELECT '00' AS year, * FROM table00 UNION ALL SELECT '01', * FROM table01 ...` и обращайтесь к нему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Необходимо объединить все таблицы (table15...) в один view с добавлением уникального идентификатора (в данном случае, последние 2 цифры года) в качестве дополнительной колонки. 
При запросе в процедуре делать join переданного в процедуру года и уникального идентификатора года. Тем самым из view будут получены записи только определенной таблицы.

Упрощенный пример:

```
declare @t1 table (id int)
declare @t2 table (id int)

insert into @t1 values(1)
insert into @t1 values(2)
insert into @t1 values(3)

insert into @t2 values(4)
insert into @t2 values(5)
insert into @t2 values(6)

select * from
(select 1 as Id, * from @t1
 union all
 select 2, * from @t2) t 
where Id = 1
```

Comment: Наверно, все же не `union`, а `union all`? Результат тот же, а серверу легче, не будет ненужной сортировки. :)

Comment: @Yaant спасибо, поправил.